# Solve matrices both algabraic and numerically

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Can someone explain me to what to do here? I don't understand the question, or how to solve the problem. Should I use some theorems, to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Hint: On $AX=B$, to solve it algebraically would be to have $X=A^{-1}B$ while numerically is to actually compute what $X$ is (i.e., the numbers in $X$).

Comment: Why A^-1 ? Do you have a link for additional information, to understand it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Micheal Burr.

One could also say, solve symbolically (by means of algebraic transformations) for the unknown $X$, e.g.
$$
A^2 X + B = 0 \iff \\
X = (A^2)^{-1}(-B) = - (A^{-1})^2 B
$$
and then insert the values for all variables and determine the resulting value for $X$, e.g. we enter $A$ and $B$ inta a computer algebra system (here Octave)

```
>> A = [ 2,2;3,4]
A =

   2   2
   3   4

>> B = [ 1,2;-1,2]
B =

   1   2
  -1   2
```

and then start calculating $X$:

```
>> inv(A)
ans =

   2.0000  -1.0000
  -1.5000   1.0000

>> X =  - inv(A)*inv(A)*B
X =

  -8.5000  -5.0000
   7.0000   4.0000
```

A little test to see if the calculation worked:

```
>> A*A*X + B
ans =

  1.4211e-014  0.0000e+000
  2.8422e-014  1.4211e-014
```

and we are done.

The objects here are (square) matrices which form an algebraic structure called a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29#Definition). It means you can pretty much calculate with them like with numbers. Notable exceptions: multiplication is not commutative in general, not all elements have multiplicative inverses.

The task can be solved by knowing

- how to add and subtract matrices,
- how to multiply a matrix with a scalar,
- how to multiply matrices and
- how to calculate the multiplicative inverse of a matrix.

Comment: Okay, I just ask again. Which rules of arithmetic do you use to isolate X? Where can I finde the information? Do you have a link?

Comment: We are using [matrix algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Basic_operations) here. This is the subject of Linear Algebra.